# how to improve my web scraping code by using multithreading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

This is my code. It is web scraping page by page and extracting the data to Excel. It is taking the next page link by extracting the anchor tag present in pagination of the current page.

Currently it is slow; can someone please help to make it fast by using multithreading or anything else?

```
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import csv

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

f = csv.writer(open('GEM.csv', 'w', newline=''))
f.writerow(['Bidnumber', 'Items', 'Quantitiy', 'Department', 'Enddate','pageNumber'])


def scrap_bid_data():
    page_no = 1
    url = ""
    while page_no <= 532:

        print('Hold on creating URL to fetch data for...'+str(page_no))
        if page_no == 2:
            url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' + "AMCR24yMNFkfoXF3wKPmGMy_wV8TJPAlxm6oWiTHGOI"
        if page_no == 1:
            url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists'

        print('URL created: ' + url)
        scraped_data = requests.get(url, verify=False)
        soup_data = bs(scraped_data.text, 'lxml')
        nextlink = soup_data.find('a', {'rel': 'next'})

        nxt = nextlink['href'].split('=')[1]
        extracted_data = soup_data.find('div', {'id': 'pagi_content'})
        if len(extracted_data) == 0:
            break
        else:
            for idx in range(len(extracted_data)):
                if (idx % 2 == 1):
                    bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')
                    if (len(bid_data) > 1):
                        print(page_no)
                        if (len(bid_data[8]) > 1 and len(bid_data[10].split(':')) > 1):
                            bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
                            items = bid_data[9].strip().split('Items:')[-1]
                            qnty = int(bid_data[10].split(':')[1].strip())
                            dept = (bid_data[11] + bid_data[16].strip()).split(":")[-1]
                            edate = bid_data[21].split("End Date:")[-1]
                            f.writerow([bidno, items, qnty, dept, edate,page_no])

        page_no=page_no+1
        url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?bidlists&page_no=' +nxt
        print('printing the next url')
        print(url)
scrap_bid_data()
```

Comment: Why do you think multithreading would help here? Your bottlenneck is almost certainly inefficiencies in the actual code. Please [edit] to show your debugging efforts. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) uses many threads. But it needs to generate all links at start. At this moment you generate next link at the end of page so using threading can't help.

Comment: you can find modules which runs `requests` with `threading`, `multiprocessing` or `asyncio`. ie. [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/) uses `aync`

Comment: @furas pls help me to do it i don't know

Comment: in all situations first you have to put code in `function` - it has to get single url and return scraped data. And next you can run for-loop which use threading, multiprocessing or asyncio to run this function with different url in separated thread, proccess. So first  try to create function which works only with one URL.

Comment: I can't even connect with this url so I can't test any code.